# Empty space on left and right even after fixing html width

Tags: html, css

Can anybody tell me why am i getting empty space on left and right of html body in this link [click here](http://xklsv.me). I am using mozilla firefox. I have even tried reducing width of html tag to 980px. I am getting horizontal scroll bar because of that extra space on left and right. Please help.

Comment: Not many here on SO will click on an external link.  Please take the time to post the problem code.  You can make a jsfiddle as well.

Comment: I don't get a horizontal scroll-bar unless I shrink the width of my browser to around 980px which would be the expected result...  Are you developing off a netbook or what?  Your resolution has to be less than 980px wide to get a scrollbar here.

Comment: @Lowkase makes a good point, I was hesitant, then I remembered I was on a company PC and didn't really care :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first div under your header div (under `<div id="header">`) has this inline style

```
width: 100px;
margin: auto;
height: auto;
border: 0px solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
padding-right: 1160px;
padding-left: 95px;
```

Look at padding-right. Is that meant to be like that? Removing that gets rid of your horizontal scroll bar. It does nudge your header around a bit, but that may be your culprit. Or you could just do what Spring said, but that's not really clearing the issue as your jus hiding the overflowing elements and not stopping it from overflowing in the first place.

Its quite hard to do much more using Firebug on your site because there is so much going on (you have over **40** scripts loaded!) that the DOM keeps changing. You might wanna clean up some of those scripts and get rid of stuff you don't need, you're adding a lot of unnecessary bloat which will slow down your site, but that's a whole other subject.

Comment: I endorse this answer : <div id="header">
<div style="width:100px;margin:auto;**padding-right:1160px; padding-left:95px;**height:auto;border:0px solid #333333;">
<ul id="nav">
<li>

Comment: oh god! how did i miss such a big error. Thank you Rob and all.. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well spotted! It looks like the site was built by a hosted platform (cloudfare.com?) with some type of site building tool.  There a quite q few inline styles, a bit of a mess to maintain unless you use the original site building tool.  Modify at one's own risk!

Comment: One of those random things you don't spot until you start digging. Luckily most of my web development life is spent in Firebug so I'm quite good at using it efficiently. Hope you get it all sorted, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can add to body element this style

`body
{
  overflow-x: hidden;
}`

I tried this style using fierbug and it worked for your page